# Autoincrement counter for my id (Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Newbie here. My target is to have a manual auto increment counter for my **fightID**. I already have a primary key which is the **ID** and it's autoincrement already on my database. My target is, to have another autoincrement. I provided a screenshot below for better visualization.

[image]

**Views:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('arena/creates')?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fight No.</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="fightID"   aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="FIGHT NUMBER" value=""> //I want to have this an auto increment counter
                    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function creates(){
        $this->arenas->createData();
        redirect("arena/arenalist");
    }
```

Model:

```
function createData() {
       
        
        $data = array (
            'fightID' => '',
           
   );
        $this->db->insert('fight_entries', $data);
       
        
}
```

Comment: retrieve last `fightID` and add 1 in that and insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the question but:

1. If you want to have the `fight_number` column in database to `AUTO_INCREMENT` automatically, you can alter the table and set

```
$fields = array(
        'column_name' => array(
                'auto_increment' => TRUE
        ),
);
$this->dbforge->modify_column('table_name', $fields);
```

2. If you want to manually increment the value, you can simply just make a DESC Select on `figt_number` so you would have the last value you have stored and for the new item you want to add, you just increment by one the value you got from the database;

I hope this gives you an idea on how to proceed;